# Arduino standalone with 9V battery and accelerometer

Tags: arduino, batteries, accelerometer

I'm using an Arduino Mega for a project involving an accelerometer. Everything works fine when the board is connected via USB. When I use a 9V battery plugged in with the 2.1mm jack, values are completely messed up.

I'm using a [MMA7260Q](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Accelerometers/MMA7260Q-Rev1.pdf) triple axis accelerometer, which gives an analog voltage for each of the three outputs. The voltage is in ratio to the measured acceleration and to the supply voltage. In order to read the correct values the following code is required: (in the 800 mV/g mode)

```
 int accValX = analogRead(A0);

 accX = (((accValX*5000.0)/1023.0)-X_0)/800;
```

Probably the voltage is not constant and that affects the acceleration readings.

I've connected the sensor as shown below. The picture is from this [tutorial](https://chalmersphyscomp10.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/mma7260q/), the board I've used is the Mega version. The 9v battery is used with the 2.1mm jack and a power adapter as show [here](http://www.emartee.com/Images/websites/emartee.com/arduino_battery_adapter_2.png).

[image]

- Am I using the correct set up to power on the board? Or should I use the Vin pin to supply the 9V...
- I've read in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70903/arduino-wont-run-well-on-9v-battery) question that 9V batteries are not the best choice to power on the Arduino for a standalone application. What does a LiPo-powered setup require?

Comment: Can you show the circuit? Sound like grounding issues.

Comment: I'm drawing it with Fritzing. Anyway it works well when connected via usb.

Comment: It does not matter what the drawing is made with, just show it. The difference between the battery and USB is the floating ground.

Comment: @EugeneSh. please see the edited post.

Comment: LiPo powering will require a LDO 3.6V regulator, reducing the MCU frequency to below 12MHz, and setting the BOR to 2.7V.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What about applications with sensors requiring a 5V power source?

Comment: @narutov6 The schematic looks perfectly fine unless you have messed some connections. How do you monitor the values? With the USB connection?

Comment: Then either switch to a buck-boost converter or use part of the MCU as a boost converter.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Values are stored and used for estimation purposes. The estimated angle is accurate with the USB but has a remarkable offset with the 9V batt. Values are sent via Xbee to a pc running matlab and then plotted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams A 2S LiPo batt with a 5V linear regulator like this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/107?

Comment: You don't want a linear regulator if you're going to go with a voltage drop that high.

Comment: Something seems fishy here - you are powering the accelerometer off the Arduino's regulated 3.3v so it shouldn't be sensitive to unregulated supply voltage.  What is your voltage on the battery under load?  What is your voltage on the 3.3v rail, and on the accelerometer output?  Note that there are probably better solutions, such as digital output accelerometers.  A typical modern micro-quadcopter board contains a 6 axis gyro/accelerometer chip, a reprogrammable microcontroller (varies), a bidirectional 2.4 GHz radio and is already designed for battery power in a small, inexpensive board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has one of three probable causes.

Cheap or dead 9V battery.

Current draw too much for a 9V battery.

A bad linear regulator on Vin.

Try a new 9V, and not a dollar store brand. If that doesn't work, try a 7.5 to 12 volt adaptor on Vin. This will help eliminate the three probable cause.

Usb bypasses both the linear regulator and avoids the low quality current issue of 9V batteries. A cheap solution for Lipo battery packs are using usb battery packs, they are lipos with charging circuitry, cutoff and boost to 5V. No mudding of the pack or Arduino needed

Comment: A cheap 9v battery was the problem.